# International Credit Card Vs PayPal Account

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, finance, payment-processing

Please let me know how international payment flow is.

Let's assume that I would like to make online payment process, 
some say that I need to have PayPal Account already,
 but to create these account I think I also need to have international credit card.

What I would like to know is,
Is it not possible to make online payment by having international credit card alone ?

Next Question is, 
let assume that I have both International bank account and PayPal Account, 

then do I need to make any deposit money to PayPal Account to make buying process?

Final Question is,
When I purchase products ,then money need to withdraw from which accounts 
[International bank account] or [my PayPay account].

Please let me get suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just link a credit card (which are almost always international) to your PayPal account.

1. yes it's possible, but it's easier for website developers to have paypal worry about input forms (and charging) than implementing their own. Note that you don't actually have to be a registered PayPal user to actually pay with a credit-card
2. PayPal will charge the credit card whenever there's a charge payment. If you are getting money, it will stay in the PayPal account - for next time maybe. You could also request to have the money sent to your bank account, but I think they charge for that
3. Whenever you make a payment with PayPal, it will charge your credit card.

Basically PayPal is just a service provider, if there's a card linked to it it acts like an easier online payment system.

Hope this helps

Comment: you solution really help me, thank.